# Expansion of $\sqrt{(a+3i)^2+x^2}$ with $x,a\in \mathbb R,\ x>>a, 3$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

I know that if we only have $\sqrt{a^2+x^2}$ with $a,x\in \mathbb R,\ x>>a$, then we do the normal Taylor expansion around $\frac{a}{x}<<1$, but what if I want to expand something like $\sqrt{(a+3i)^2+x^2}$ with $x,a\in \mathbb R,\ x>>a, 3$? I do not know how to expand this. Thank you.

Comment: Taylor expansion works the same way with complex numbers.

Comment: @Andrei so this would just be $\sqrt{(a+3i)^2+x^2}=x \sqrt{1+y^2}=x(1+\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{y^4}{8}+..)$ with $y=\frac{(a+3i)}{x}$?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}{} $

Comment: @Andrei Thanks a lot!